# Can I use a quilt with a bivi bag?

Tags: gear, wild-camping

Is it possible (read, can I spend a restful night sleeping?) By using a quilt, bivi bag and ground sheet?

Quilt I'm looking at is [here](https://www.ultralightoutdoorgear.co.uk/equipment-c3/sleeping-bags-c21/sleeping-bags-c88/duvet-down-blanket-p3081), the idea being that I can take an ultralight bivi bag and groundsheet in addition to my hammock setup (which includes the quilt) so I'm covered whatever the terrain without having to carry two sleeping bags.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use the quilt that comes with your hammock *instead* of carrying an additional sleeping bag? Or are you thinking about buying *another* quilt, in addition to the one that come with your hammock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ground sheet should not be necessary -- the bivi bag should protect you from a wet, dirty ground -- but you will need a sleeping pad under you for insulation from a cold ground. Having a duvet instead of a sleeping bag should save you money and weight and, given that you have the bivi bag, draft should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, but it likely wouldn't keep you as warm underneath unless you wrapped it all the way around, in which case you have almost duplicated a sleeping bag.

Depending on the temperature it might work great, or it could be miserable and a lot of that depends on you. Just try to test it out in safe place before you go on some crazy expedition where you have to depend on it.

Comment: Down compresses underneath you and does not insulate you nearly as effectively. That's why you use a sleeping pad, and if you pair a quilt (whether flat or shaped) with a properly insulating pad, you'll be fine.

Comment: @JonathanPatt Would you still use a pad in a hammock setup?

Comment: In a hammock, outside of hot summer nights where you want the cooling effects of a hammock, I would use a pad under me if I didn't have an underquilt to attach to the outside of the hammock for insulation.

Comment: @JonathanPatt You also use a sleeping pad when sleeping on the ground because the ground will carry your body heat away a lot faster than the air.

Answer (score 3):

All a quilt is, is a sleeping bag without a zipper.

I have a down barrel sleeping bag rated to -10°C that is advertised as being useful as a duvet/quilt in summer months.

You can use a quilt in any situation you would use a sleeping bag, but you're more likely to feel a draft if you don't tuck the ends in just right.